# Where does Steam store library directories?

Tags: settings, steam

In Steam, we can configure multiple directories/folders where it will look for applications. It is found in the menu `Steam->Settings->Downloads->STEAM LIBRARY FOLDERS` dialog.

Where can I find those settings if I'm looking programatically from outside Steam?

I'm more interested in the location for the Windows client.

Answer (score 6):

Found it. On Windows they are stored in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\libraryfolders.vdf`, and you also have to add Steam's install folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam`. On Debian, stored in `~/.local/share/Steam/steamapps/libraryfolders.vdf`.

Here's a sample Python script to extract the information on Windows:

```python
import re
with open(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\SteamApps\libraryfolders.vdf") as f:
    folders = [r"C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam"]
    lf = f.read()
    folders.extend([fn.replace("\\\\", "\\") for fn in
        re.findall('^\s*"\d*"\s*"([^"]*)"', lf, re.MULTILINE)])
```

Comment: This sample script (as it is currently written) will not work if Steam itself is not installed in the `Program Files` folder.

Comment: This is actually only partially true. Steam stores one global config in `${YOURAPS}\Steam\config\libraryfolders.vdf` but it does overwrite it with the setting in the respective libraries where it also stores a libraryfolders.vdf (for each library you create). In linux its `${HOME}\.local\share\Steam\config`, btw. 

If your library e.g. includes `/myLib1/SteamLibrary/` then Steam stores a `/myLib1/SteamLibrary/libraryfolder.vdf` there. This just contains a contentid but also a **label**. You override that there (especially for fileshare which are blank)

Answer (score 4):

I found it here:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\config\config.vdf
```

There's a line in that file:

```
"BaseInstallFolder_1"       "{YourSteamLibraryFolder}"
```

So I just open it with Notepad then Ctrl+F search 'Base'.

If that line is not in there:

1. Open Steam. > Sign into you account. > 'Steam'. > 'Settings'.
2. Then click on 'Downloads'. > 'STEAM LIBRARY FOLDERS'.
3. Make an empty folder somewhere.
4. Click on 'ADD LIBRARY FOLDER'.
5. Browse to the empty folder you made. > Click on 'SELECT'.

If you then look at the config.vdf again; there should be a line like this:

```
"BaseInstallFolder_1"       "{YourNewEmptySteamLibraryFolder}"
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Editing the files does the trick. Changing installation library location seems impossible, especially on drive C.

Answer (score 0):

If Steam hasn't been installed in the default location in Windows, you can find it in the registry under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`, on path `SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam`. Here's how I found it in Kotlin:

```
private val steamFolder: File = File(WinRegistry.getString(
    WinRegistry.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,
    "SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Valve\\Steam",
    "InstallPath"))
```

You can then find the `libraryfolders.vdf` and `config.vdf` files, as per the other answers.

In each of those library folders you'll find files called `appmanifest_<id>.acf`, where `<id>` is the id of the game (find it in Properties / Updates on Steam). If you're looking for a particular game, that will help to determine which folder the game is in, if there's more than one game install location.

Answer (score 0):

here is a small tool that can retrieve steam library folders.

https://github.com/ArchemedIan/steam-path-info

```
.\steam-path-info.exe steam libpaths count
3

.\steam-path-info.exe steam libpaths 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps,D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps,S:\Games\SteamLibrary\steamapps

.\steam-path-info.exe steam libpaths index 2
D:\SteamLibrary\steamapps
```